# Open files on client side from ORACLE Forms

Tags: oracle, excel, file, forms, client-side

I'm trying to put a code on a button so that the user would be able to open a specific excel file whenever he pressed it , unfortunately the code i was using ( AppID  ) happened to be opening the file on the server side not the client side ; please find the code below :

```
DECLARE
    AppID PLS_INTEGER;
BEGIN        
    AppID := DDE.App_Begin('C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office12\WINWORD.EXE    C:\test\'||:TT_PER_RF_MAIN.T_NUMBER||'.docx', DDE.APP_MODE_NORMAL);    
END;
```

Can anyone help me how to let the users ( client side ) be able to open it on thier own PCs?

Comment: What version of Oracle Forms?

Comment: Your tags are inappropriate, why do you keep rolling back? I'm trying to help you find the right audience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for the HOST command. In Forms 10g, it's in the WebUtil component.

Comment: thanks ammoq , i've tried some host commands but same problem occured , the file is opened on the server side and the users 
( clients side ) can't see it .
Can you please provide me with an exact example to see how it may work on the client side ?

Comment: You specifically need to use the WEBUTIL_HOST.HOST command, not just HOST without a package name. Plain HOST will function on the server, as you say.

Comment: Or CLIENT_HOST.  Actually, now that I've done a little checking, I know CLIENT_HOST works.  WEBUTIL_HOST.HOST should work, too.  There are other functions in the WEBUTIL_HOST package that also might work for you.

Comment: Thanks a lot Andy , i really appreciate your consern .
I have never worked on WEBUTIL_HOST , Does it need a license ? and how can i download it ? 

I'm working right now on th CLIENT_HOST method but i keep getting an error on the CLIENT_HOST ( identifier must be declared ) .
Please Andy i'll appreciated it a lot if you can help me with my issue ( i have a dead line and i don't know what to do :(  Thanks )

Comment: This PDF:
http://www.oracle.com/technology/products/forms/htdocs/webutil/web_util.pdf
Will give you all the info you need.  I don't really know any more than what's in there.

Comment: Thanks AndyDAn :D  really appreciate your help my friend